# Why django makes many session object in database?

Tags: django, django-sessions

I've got vanilla django project with app called 'app' . It has views.py and middleweres.py.

```
#views.py
from django.http.response import HttpResponse

def home(request):
    return HttpResponse('')

#settings.py

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'app.middlewares.M',
)

#middlewares.py
class M(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        request.session['a']='a'
```

Django adds a row to session table in db on every request. Why?

UPD: I'm still confused. I've made a github project for that question: https://github.com/vinograd19/django-session-problem/
You can find out my code there and run it on your machine

Comment: Can you dump session data?
Are you aware your are modifying your session in each process_request?

Comment: There is 'original' session {'_auth_user_id': 1L, '_auth_user_backend': 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend','a':'a'} and others like {'a':'a'}

Comment: does this happen also without app.middlewares.M?

Answer (score 4):

Your custom middleware M is modifying the session dictionary on every single request ([Writing your own middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/#process-request)):

> process_request() is called on each request, before Django decides which view to execute.

Even though you are modifying the session on every request, there should only be one row for every user (same visitor on the same browser). If the same visitor makes multiple requests, his corresponding session row should be **updated** on every request (because of your middleware 'M'). An additional row will not be created for the same visitor, but new rows are created as new visitors come to your website. From Django docs:

> consider what happens with the database backend. When a user logs in, Django adds a row to the django_session database table. Django updates this row each time the session data changes. If the user logs out manually, Django deletes the row. But if the user does not log out, the row never gets deleted. A similar process happens with the file backend.

If you have found many rows in your **DB sessions** table, then you probably have expired sessions that need to be purged ([Clearing the session store](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#clearing-the-session-store))

> Django does not provide automatic purging of expired sessions. Therefore, it’s your job to purge expired sessions on a regular basis. Django provides a clean-up management command for this purpose: clearsessions. It’s recommended to call this command on a regular basis, for example as a daily cron job.

In this case, you should call the [clearsessions command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-clearsessions):

```
django-admin.py clearsessions
```

You should setup a cron job to regularly call this command and clean out expired sessions.

Comment: Sorry, I didn' catch. Do you mean django doesn't know a user object when it implements `M` middleware? If so, how does `messages` middleware works without knowing a user object?

Comment: Django does know a user object, if the user is logged in (see [how to get user from session](http://scottbarnham.com/blog/2008/12/04/get-user-from-session-key-in-django/) ). If the user is not logged in then you would have an anonymous session. Check the expire date of all duplicate rows in the sessions table. You will probably find that all "duplicates" are expired sessions.

Comment: As I said, session table update every on request. Session are not out of date.

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#when-sessions-are-saved):

> **When sessions are saved**
>
> By default, Django only saves to the session
> database when the session has been modified – that is if any of its
> dictionary values have been assigned or deleted:

Comment: so? session dict doesn't being changed.